# Downloading file on anchor click

Tags: c#, xpath, puppeteer-sharp

I having problem making a file download work when pushing a `<a>` with Puppeteer-sharp in headless mode.

I have this kind of html:

```
<div>
    <a href="https:/DOWNLOAD"></a>
    <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

In headless mode = FALSE, everything is working, pushing the  anchor tack download the file to the browser download folder, and pushing the  tag is also working.

but if I switch the mode to headless = TRUE, then the file is not downloaded, I very sure that puppeteer are clicking the  tag as I get no error running the code. The button click is working. I tried search all my c-drive but I cannot find the file that is supposed to be downloaded anywhere. I tried taking some jpg dumps and all seams to work.

Any help on how to make it possible for Puppeteer-sharp to work in headless mode and still be able to download files when clicking a  link?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

Adding this to the IPage object:

```
        await page.Client.SendAsync("Page.setDownloadBehavior", new
        {
            behavior = "allow",
            downloadPath = Path
        });
```

made the file download also in headless mode.